# Keras error: the graph couldn't be sorted in topological order

Tags: python, keras, lstm, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to built a Conv-LSTM model but I get the following warning : `E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:697] Iteration = 0, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.`

This is my python script:

```
from keras.layers import Conv1D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling1D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import RepeatVector
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(128, 6, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 6, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(RepeatVector(n_outputs))
model.add(LSTM(200, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(100, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
```

What does it mean? What could likely cause this problem and how to avoid it?

Comment: I am able to compile your code, I haven't faced any error. Can you try to decrease the batch size and try.

Comment: I can compile the script on jupyter notebook without any problem but when i try to turn it on anaconda prompt i get the error

Comment: i don't get this error when i compile a simple CNN or LSTM model